# Problems with AsyncTask/Thread and networkonmainthreadexception

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask

Hello Guys,
I wanted to make an chat-client for my Android. But I just can't get any connection.
Well, maybe you can help me a bit..
In my MainActivity.java I call:

```java
//connect to the server
SocketTask connection = new SocketTask(this); 
connection.execute();
```

My SocketTask.java looks as follows:

```java
package chat.client;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class SocketTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    private Socket socket;
    private DataInputStream input;
    protected PrintStream output;
    private MainActivity main;
    private Thread thrd;

    public SocketTask(MainActivity main){
        this.main = main;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            socket = new Socket("192.168.178.23", 1338);
            input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            output = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            // submittes the name of the client
            output.println("Mobile");
            output.flush();
            thrd = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                        try {
                            final String data = input.readLine();
                            if (data != null)
                                main.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    //new Runnable(){
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        if(!data.equals("")){
                                            //main.chatHistory.append(data+"\n");
                                            main.addText(data);
                                        }else{
                                            //chatHistory.append("\n");
                                            main.addText("");
                                        }

                                    }
                                });
                            //};
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            //chatHistory.append("Verbindung zum Server abgebrochen!");
                            main.addText("Verbindung zum Server abgebrochen!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            thrd.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //chatHistory.append("Es konnte keine Verbindung zum Server aufgebaut werden!");
            main.addText("Es konnte keine Verbindung zum Server aufgebaut werden!"+e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

But when I launch it, I only get:
02-27 16:32:05.875: E/SensorManager(26146): thread start

Also, when I try to call "connection.doInBackground()" instead of "connection.execute()" (I know that this doesn't make any sense at all), I get a "networkonmainthreadexception" - but I thought I've fixed that already with an AsyncTask. Well, I'm new to Android, but I already googled a lot, don't know if I'm that stupid but now I gave up and so I registered me here. Maybe someone of you can tell me, what I'm doing wrong..

(Not sure if I need to post my MainActivity-class..)
Thank you! :)

Edit: Thanks guys for all these answers, right know I'm a bit overextended, just give me some time to try out / understand all your tips, thanks!

Comment: Where is the exception thrown? What line number and class? The more details the better.

Comment: If you call doInBackground directly you are bypassing the actual threaded portion that is normally created by calling "execute". Hence you are just running doInBackground as any other method call on the thread you called it from which is why you got that error.

Comment: You are going to need to post a bit more of the stack trace to see what is causing the exception. connection.execute() is the right way to go, but maybe something else is causing the problem.

Comment: u are trying to access UI elements from doInBackground()

Comment: this is what my logcat says: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9a3e5hgi2kmmuwn/log.pdf

Comment: well, I thought I bypass this UI-thingy by using main.addText(); (and then my addText method modifies the gui..)

Comment: You really need to redesign your SocketTask. You start yet another thread in the background thread that runs doInBackground. Fix this by properly implementing onPostExecute and onProgressUpdate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception says that you need to run your network operations on background thread. Calling directly doInBackground() just makes everything run in the same thread the call was made, main one, obviously. So, you have to spawn new one with `connection.excute()`.
But, you can not update UI elements from background thread. To do it on the main thread, you need to implement `onProgressUpdate()` for your AsyncTask like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... arg) {            
        main.addText(arg[0]);
    }
```

now, replace all calls of `addText()` in `doInBackground()` with `publishProgress("whatever");`. Don't forget to change Async task declaration to `AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>`.
When you complete everything above, you won't need to spawn another thread inside `doInBackground()`, it will be executed in background thread anyways.
Although, your current code does about the same, this will resolve the mess (no more `thrd = new Thread(new Runnable() {...` and `main.runOnUiThread...`) and probably fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

there're A LOT of conceptual errors on the implementation of the AsyncTask that is really difficult to even try to figure out why or what can be going wrong, so I'll write here a recipe and a feel tips on how to write a AsyncTask and you apply them, if you still get errors then you ask again:

**tips:**

- do not create a new thread inside the AsyncTask, the doInBackground() is already being called in a background thread
- do not call runOnUiThread on the AsyncTask, the onPostExecute() is already called on the UI thread
- If your activity pauses (onPause() is called) call .pause() on your AsyncTask or else you probably will have some `NullPointerException`
- Do not directly call `doInBackground()` as you suggested, the `execute()` call will create a new thread and call it for you (that's why the AsyncTask is for)
- do not hold the activity object or any other that holds the context to your AsyncTask. Simply put the AsyncTask class declaration inside the Activity itself, and, for organisation purposes, make doInbackground() call one method in a different class with the actual processing. That way your onPostExecute can call the UI to update it, but you keep data gethering/procesing separate from activity

**recipe:**

```
// put this class inside your Activity and
// just call a separate class (for organisation),
// or just put the code all in there (for no organisation)
private class SocketTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // Whatever you do inside here
    // DO NOT create a new thread!
    return APIConnection.callAPI();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if(result!=null){
    //Update your UI here
    }else{
    // Some error happen?
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Yes!  The first problem is that it even attempts to *use* an AT for this purpose!  Who is it that said: "To an Android programmer, every concurrency problem looks like an AsyncTask?"

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to work with your `MainActivity` in the `doInBackground()` this needs to be in the `onPostExecute()` method which runs on the `UI` thread and the `doInBackground()` method does not.

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

> The 4 steps
>
> When an asynchronous task is executed, the task goes through 4 steps:
>
> onPreExecute(), invoked on the UI thread before the task is executed.
>   This step is normally used to setup the task, for instance by showing
>   a progress bar in the user interface.
>
> doInBackground(Params...), invoked on the background thread
>   immediately after onPreExecute() finishes executing. This step is used
>   to perform background computation that can take a long time. The
>   parameters of the asynchronous task are passed to this step. The
>   result of the computation must be returned by this step and will be
>   passed back to the last step. This step can also use
>   publishProgress(Progress...) to publish one or more units of progress.
>   These values are published on the UI thread, in the
>   onProgressUpdate(Progress...) step.
>
> onProgressUpdate(Progress...), invoked on the UI thread after a call
>   to publishProgress(Progress...). The timing of the execution is
>   undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in the
>   user interface while the background computation is still executing.
>   For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in
>   a text field.
>
> onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background
>   computation finishes. The result of the background computation is
>   passed to this step as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, thank you @MikeD, I just don't use that as much so I'm used to saying `onPostExecute()`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying running something on the main the thread the way you have, with `AsynTask`, if you need to run something on the main thread (i.e. the UI), you would call `publishProgess()` from `doInBackground(...)`, which in turn calls `onProgressUpdate(...)`. Do not call `doInBackground` directly, `execute()` is the proper way to start an `AsyncTask`. When the `doInBackground()` has returned, `onPostExecute()` will be called automatically on the main thread.

The [Android docs on `AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) are very good, and has a good usage example.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the required permission in the manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: This answer is best suited as a comment.

Comment: Sorry, I answerd this because many times this is the source of such problems.

Comment: @AdorjanPrincz Lots of times it is.